# single byte xor decryption code

Tags: rust

I've recently started learning rust and doing cryptopals as exercise.
I coded a program that decrypts single xor cypher. The algorithm I came up with is very simple and probably not efficient, but I would like more emphasis on rust philosophy and syntax

````
extern crate hex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let ciphertext = "1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736";
    let ciphertext_bytes = hex::decode(ciphertext).unwrap();
    let xor_key = find_xor_key(&ciphertext_bytes);
    println!("{}", ciphertext_bytes.iter().map(|x|(x^xor_key) as char ).collect::<String>());
}

fn find_xor_key(ciphertext: &Vec<u8>) -> u8{

    let mut max_score = 0;
    let mut best_key = 0;
    for xor_key in 1..255{
        let xored_vec = ciphertext.iter().map(|x|x^xor_key).collect(); 
        let score = get_score(xored_vec);
        if score > max_score{
            max_score = score;
            best_key = xor_key;
        } 
    }
    println!("{}", max_score);
    
    best_key
}

fn get_score(text: Vec<u8>) -> u8
{
    let ideal_frequencies: HashMap<char, f32> = [
    
('E', 11.1607),
('M', 3.0129),
('A', 8.4966),
('H', 3.0034),
('R', 7.5809),
('G', 2.4705),
('I', 7.5448),
('B', 2.0720),
('O', 7.1635),
('F', 1.8121),
('T', 6.9509),
('Y', 1.7779),
('N', 6.6544),
('W', 1.2899),
('S', 5.7351),
('K', 1.1016),
('L', 5.4893),
('V', 1.0074),
('C', 4.5388),
('X', 0.2902),
('U', 3.6308),
('Z', 0.2722),
('D', 3.3844),
('J', 0.1965),
('P', 3.1671),
('Q', 0.1962),
    
    ].iter().cloned().collect();

    for byte in text.clone(){
        let char_rep: char =  byte as char;
        if !char_rep.is_ascii(){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    let mut score = 1;
    let chars: Vec<char> = text.iter().cloned().map(|x|x as char).collect();
    let frequencies: HashMap<char, f32> = calculate_frequencies(&chars.into_iter().collect::<String>()); 

    for (letter, frequency) in &frequencies{
        if ideal_frequencies.contains_key(&letter) && //already checked here that it exists in the hashmap
        f32::abs(frequency - ideal_frequencies.get(&letter).unwrap()) <= 10.0{
            score += 1;
        } 
    }
    score
}


fn calculate_frequencies(text: &str) ->HashMap<char, f32>{

    let mut frequencies: HashMap<char, f32> = HashMap::new();
    let mut letter_counts:HashMap<char, i32> = HashMap::new();
    let text_upper = text.to_ascii_uppercase();
    for c in text_upper.chars(){
        let count = letter_counts.entry(c).or_insert(0);
        *count += 1;        
    }
    for (c, count) in letter_counts{
        frequencies.entry(c).or_insert(count as f32 / text_upper.len() as f32 * 100.0);
    }
    frequencies
}
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
extern crate hex;
```

`extern crate` is generally not necessary for programs since the 2018 (currently latest) edition of Rust. You should be able to delete this line, provided that `edition = "2018"` is in your `Cargo.toml` file.

---

```rust
let ciphertext_bytes = hex::decode(ciphertext).unwrap();
```

If you change `.unwrap` to `.expect("failed to decode ciphertext")` then there'll be a little more information in the error message. Of course, for a well-made command line program, you'd want to print your own better-formatted error message, instead of a Rust "panic" error.

---

```rust
fn find_xor_key(ciphertext: &Vec<u8>) -> u8{
```

Accepting `&Vec<u8>` is usually overly restrictive because it requires the caller to have constructed a `Vec`, whereas if you change the type to `&[u8]` they can pass any *slice* of bytes. This will work without needing to change `main`, because `Vec` *derefs* to a byte slice.

The same applies to `get_score`'s parameter, but you'll need to tweak a couple things to make that work, like giving `xored_vec` the explicit type `Vec<u8>` and changing `byte as char` to `*byte as char`.

---

```rust
    let ideal_frequencies: HashMap<char, f32> = [
...
    ].iter().cloned().collect();
```

This is basically a constant, so it'd be nice if we can compute this hash map only once rather than every time we check a score. We can do that with the [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.5.2/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) crate, which will hopefully soon become [part of the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/lazy/struct.Lazy.html). Like this:

```rust
static IDEAL_FREQUENCIES: Lazy<HashMap<char, f32>> = Lazy::new(|| [
    ('E', 11.1607),
    ...
].iter().cloned().collect());
```

---

```rust
for byte in text.clone(){
```

Use `text.iter()` instead of `text.clone()`; it avoids allocating a copy. In general, where both are available, `.into_iter()` consumes the structure and iterates over its elements by value (moves them), and `.iter()` does not consume the structure but iterates over references to its elements instead.

---

```rust
let char_rep: char =  byte as char;
if !char_rep.is_ascii(){
```

You can just use `if !byte.is_ascii() {` here.

---

```rust
let chars: Vec<char> = text.iter().cloned().map(|x|x as char).collect();
let frequencies: HashMap<char, f32> = calculate_frequencies(&chars.into_iter().collect::<String>());
```

`.cloned().map(|x|x as char)` can be written as `.map(|x| *x as char)`.

You're collecting into `chars` and then immediately iterate to convert it to a `String`; that isn't necessary because you can just write

```rust
calculate_frequencies(&text.iter().map(|x| *x as char).collect::<String>())
```

But, there's a bigger point: `text` was already an `&[u8]`, and if we want a `&str` out of that, that's just [`std::str::from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html).

```rust
calculate_frequencies(std::str::from_utf8(text).unwrap())
```

(`.unwrap()` will never fail here because we already checked that every byte is ASCII, so it cannot be invalid UTF-8.)

---

Your loop over the frequencies has several unnecessary `&`s, and also looks up in the hash map twice instead of once; here's both fixed:

```rust
for (letter, frequency) in frequencies.iter() {
    if let Some(ideal_frequency) = IDEAL_FREQUENCIES.get(letter) {
        if (frequency - ideal_frequency).abs() <= 10.0 {
            score += 1;
        }
    } 
}
```

---

```rust
fn calculate_frequencies(text: &str) ->HashMap<char, f32>{
```

If we want to optimize for performance, which a real code-breaking tool would want to do, then this function should be accepting `&[u8]`, since the only thing it does with the `str` is split back to characters, and we know all the characters are ASCII at this point. But for more general idiomatic programming, taking `&str` is fine.

---

```rust
let mut frequencies: HashMap<char, f32> = HashMap::new();
let mut letter_counts:HashMap<char, i32> = HashMap::new();
```

You can leave out the type declarations here and they will be inferred.

---

```rust
let text_upper = text.to_ascii_uppercase();
for c in text_upper.chars(){
```

This allocates a `String` of uppercase unnecessarily; we might as well do it per-character instead:

```rust
for c in text.chars() {
    let c = c.to_ascii_uppercase();
```

(Note, however, that this strategy does not work for Unicode-aware uppercasing, where one `char` may occasionally become several.)

---

This is not a matter of Rust idiom at all, but I notice that `frequencies` is identical to `letter_counts` except for the values getting scaled. So, we can reuse a single `HashMap` instead of duplicating it:

```rust
fn calculate_frequencies(text: &str) ->HashMap<char, f32>{
    let count_to_frequency_scale = 100.0 / text.len() as f32;
    
    let mut counts = HashMap::new();
    for c in text.chars() {
        *counts.entry(c.to_ascii_uppercase()).or_insert(0.0) += 1.0;
    }
    
    // Rescale counts to frequencies
    for count in counts.values_mut() {
        *count *= count_to_frequency_scale;
    }
    counts
}
```

Note: Using `f32` instead of `i32` for counting does not introduce any floating-point error, for reasonable string lengths: `f32` exactly represents all integers up to 2<sup>24</sup> - 1 = 16,777,216. (However, there *would* be accumulated error if we tried to apply `count_to_frequency_scale` while counting instead of after.)

If it didn't happen to be possible to reuse the same map, I'd be suggesting using iterators to do the transformation instead:

```rust
letter_counts
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(key, count)| (key, count as f32 * count_to_frequency_scale))
    .collect()
```

---

Here's your code with all of my suggestions, and also formatted with `rustfmt`. I haven't tested it because I was working in the [*Rust Playground*](https://play.rust-lang.org/) which doesn't include the `hex` crate in its available libraries.

````rust
extern crate hex;
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn main() {
    let ciphertext = "1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736";
    let ciphertext_bytes = hex::decode(ciphertext).unwrap();
    let xor_key = find_xor_key(&ciphertext_bytes);
    println!(
        "{}",
        ciphertext_bytes
            .iter()
            .map(|x| (x ^ xor_key) as char)
            .collect::<String>()
    );
}

fn find_xor_key(ciphertext: &[u8]) -> u8 {
    let mut max_score = 0;
    let mut best_key = 0;
    for xor_key in 1..255 {
        let xored_vec: Vec<u8> = ciphertext.iter().map(|x| x ^ xor_key).collect();
        let score = get_score(&xored_vec);
        if score > max_score {
            max_score = score;
            best_key = xor_key;
        }
    }
    println!("{}", max_score);

    best_key
}

fn get_score(text: &[u8]) -> u8 {
    for byte in text.iter() {
        if !byte.is_ascii() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    let mut score = 1;
    let frequencies = calculate_frequencies(std::str::from_utf8(text).unwrap());

    for (letter, frequency) in frequencies.iter() {
        if let Some(ideal_frequency) = IDEAL_FREQUENCIES.get(letter) {
            if (frequency - ideal_frequency).abs() <= 10.0 {
                score += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    score
}

fn calculate_frequencies(text: &str) -> HashMap<char, f32> {
    let count_to_frequency_scale = 100.0 / text.len() as f32;

    let mut counts = HashMap::new();
    for c in text.chars() {
        *counts.entry(c.to_ascii_uppercase()).or_insert(0.0) += 1.0;
    }

    // Rescale counts to frequencies
    for count in counts.values_mut() {
        *count *= count_to_frequency_scale;
    }
    counts
}

static IDEAL_FREQUENCIES: Lazy<HashMap<char, f32>> = Lazy::new(|| {
    [
        ('E', 11.1607),
        ('M', 3.0129),
        ('A', 8.4966),
        ('H', 3.0034),
        ('R', 7.5809),
        ('G', 2.4705),
        ('I', 7.5448),
        ('B', 2.0720),
        ('O', 7.1635),
        ('F', 1.8121),
        ('T', 6.9509),
        ('Y', 1.7779),
        ('N', 6.6544),
        ('W', 1.2899),
        ('S', 5.7351),
        ('K', 1.1016),
        ('L', 5.4893),
        ('V', 1.0074),
        ('C', 4.5388),
        ('X', 0.2902),
        ('U', 3.6308),
        ('Z', 0.2722),
        ('D', 3.3844),
        ('J', 0.1965),
        ('P', 3.1671),
        ('Q', 0.1962),
    ]
    .iter()
    .cloned()
    .collect()
});
```
````